# Interval field in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, intervals, seconds

What is the difference between these commands?

```
ALTER TABLE podcast_episodes ADD COLUMN duration interval;

ALTER TABLE podcast_episodes ADD COLUMN duration interval SECOND(0);

ALTER TABLE podcast_episodes ADD COLUMN duration interval SECOND;
```

I would like to store duration of a podcast episode and later have podcast_playback_history with first_mark and last_mark to calculate percentage of the whole episode listened.

The docs said

> The interval type has an additional option, which is to restrict the set of stored fields by writing one of these phrases:

YEAR

MONTH

DAY

HOUR

MINUTE

SECOND

YEAR TO MONTH

DAY TO HOUR

DAY TO MINUTE

DAY TO SECOND

HOUR TO MINUTE

HOUR TO SECOND

MINUTE TO SECOND

> Note that if both fields and p are specified, the fields must include SECOND, since the precision applies only to the seconds.

Is there added benefit if I set it to second? Will it still be 16 bytes or will it be less?
I tried using second and second(0), when I save the row it is still showing as '0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 2.00 secs'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The added `fields` specification determines how strings with unmarked quantities are interpreted.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT)

> When writing an interval constant with a fields specification, or when
> assigning a string to an interval column that was defined with a
> fields specification, the interpretation of unmarked quantities
> depends on the fields. For example `INTERVAL '1' YEAR` is read as 1
> year, whereas `INTERVAL '1'` means 1 second.

I ***never*** use these modifiers for the type definition. Better stick to default intervals and avoid confusion. Always spell out quantity names in string literals (`interval '13 seconds'` or `interval '13 sec'`), never `interval '13'` - the only case where the added type modifier would kick in. I wouldn't want to depend on the table definition to interpret my input. Especially not for such an infrequently used feature.

The optional precision modifier `(0)` .. `(6)` only applies to seconds and is only allowed together with that field specification. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)

> Note that if both ***`fields`*** and ***`p`*** are specified, the
> fields must include `SECOND`, since the precision applies only to the seconds.

It defines how many decimal digits are stored for sub-seconds. If you use it (which I would **not**), be aware that values are **rounded**, not truncated (like one might expect).

```sql
test=> SELECT '13.555555 sec'::interval(3);
   interval   
--------------
 00:00:13.556    -- !
(1 row)

test=> SELECT '13.555555 sec'::interval(0);
 interval 
----------
 00:00:14        -- !!!
(1 row)
```

Demo:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c0461fce0cab055657079201442d9fe1)*

> Is there added benefit if I set it to `second`?

No, that's the default anyway. (And I would strongly suggest to stick with the default to avoid confusion.)

> Will it still be 16 bytes or will it be less?

The size of an `interval` value is *always* 16 bytes.